# css arrow top not working

Tags: css

I have a css arrow top that I want to display in the top of the div, like this:

[image]

the problem is, the arrow is inside the div...

what is wrong here?

```
#news { 
 position:absolute;
 min-width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000;
 border:1px solid #000;
}


#news:before {
  content: "";

  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 

  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3huzc74a/

Comment: No need of vertical align:middle and width:0 and height:0.. juz position:absolute and margin-top:-5px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your positioning code was just a little bit off. The best way to position the arrow pseudoelement (thanks to [@vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals)) is to use `bottom: 100%` along with `margin: auto`, `left: 0`, and `right: 0`. That way your arrow will always stay in the correct position even if you decide to change the arrow's size.

Here is a working **live demo**:

```css
#bellnews {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#bellnews:before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id=bellnews>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/3huzc74a/3/

Comment: A little better system to position it is bottom: 100%. If you change the border-bottom in the future, it will adjust automatically

Comment: and to center it, use   margin: auto;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;   https://jsfiddle.net/xg9ucmf5/

Comment: it is nice because need this to be position absolute, thank you friend!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one with position relative on parent and absolute on child:

```
#bellnews { 
 position:relative;
 width: 140px;
 height:100px;
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000;
 border:1px solid #000;
}


#bellnews:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  top: -5px;

  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3huzc74a/2/

Comment: It's not needed to make the news div relative. Any value for positon aside from static will create a new positioning context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make :before pseudo element `absolute` . 
Then use `top` to control the position of the pseudo element.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFtByxWjfLY) is a nice tutorial to understand the basics.
Working code

```css
#bellnews {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 140px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px
}
#bellnews:before {
  content: "";
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div id=bellnews>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent div definitely does not need to be `position: relative`. Any value for position aside from `static` will cause a new positioning context to be created.

Comment: It has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the position on the #news div relative, and the triangle absolute, it should work.

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3huzc74a/7/

```
#bellnews { 
 position: absolute;
 min-width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000;
 border:1px solid #000;
}


#bellnews:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 70px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 

  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: It's not needed to make the `news` div relative. Any value for positon aside from `static` will create a new positioning context.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister -Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using `absolute` positioning with `left:calc(50% - 5px);` will always keep it in the middle no matter the width.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/s1up1LL0/2/)

```css
#bellnews { 
 position:relative;
 min-width: 140px;
 min-height:100px;
 background: #fff; 
 color: #000;
 border:1px solid #000;
 display:inline-block;
}


#bellnews:before {
  content: "";
position:absolute;
bottom:100%;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  left:calc(50% - 5px);

  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id=bellnews>
</div>
```